# Bootstrap issue, popover, need to re-direct to link when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

im using twitter bootstrap on my site, and i wanted to enable a popover, over a list item in my navbar, but i seem to have issues with it, this is my list element:

```
<li class="danger">
    <a href="../contest.php"></i> Contest</a>
</li>
```

now, if i do this:

```
<li class="danger">
    <a href="../contest.php" id="contestPop" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="title" data-content="content"></i> Contest</a>
</li>
```

The link does not work, the popup toggles, but i havnt set it to toogle, i call it like this:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     var seenAdd = $.cookie("Add")

     if (seenAdd == 1) {

        return;
     } else {

        $.cookie("Add", 1, { path: '/' }, { expires: 30 }); 
        setTimeout(function (){ $("#contestPop").popover("show");},2000);
        setTimeout(function (){ $("#contestPop").popover("destroy");},8000);
     };
});
```

EDIT: If i place the popover elsewere, the link does not stay where it is supposed to...

Comment: what's with the </i> tag?

Comment: woops, i forgot the start <i> in the post

Answer (score 0):

Change the url `../contest.php` for **hashtag** (`#`) or `javascript:;` and remove the element `<i>`;. It's wrong.

You can use the popover this way:

```
<li class="danger">
<a href="#" id="contestPop" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="title" data-content="content"> Contest</a>
```

and in your JS:

```
$(function ()  { $("#contestPop").popover();  });
```

Obs.: Don't forget the Jquery.